# Plot a legend for both a barplot and a line

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

If I have a barplot and then a line on the same graph, how do I write a legend for both? I have

```
hold on
h1 = bar([x;y], 0.5);
h2 = plot(a, b);
l = cell(2,1);
l{1,1}='Label for x';
l{2,1}='Label for y';
hl=legend(h1, l);
set(hl,'FontSize',10,'Location','Northeast', 'Orientation', 'horizontal');
```

This generates the legend for the barplot but how do I add the legend entry for the line plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only passed the `bar` plot handle to the `legend` function so that's all it's going to create. What you can do, however, is pass an *array* of handles (and labels) to `legend` and legend entries for all elements of the handles array will be shown.

```
h1 = bar([x;y], 0.5);
h2 = plot(a, b);
labels = {'Label for x', 'Label for y'};
L = legend([h1, h2], labels, ...
            'FontSize', 10, ...
            'Location', 'Northeast', ...
            'Orientation', 'horizontal');
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
legend({'label for x','label for y'},'FontSize',10,'Location','Northeast','Orientation','vertical');
```

If you want to keep your cell object with the legend entries, you can use

```
l = cell(2,1);
l{1,1}='Label for x';
l{2,1}='Label for y';
legend(l,'FontSize',10,'Location','Northeast','Orientation', 'vertical');
```